# How can I show items belonging to a logged in user in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to show the emails that the logged in user has sent from the database

This is the route code:

```
Route::get('/myEmails/{id}','PagesController@myEmailsShow');
```

This is the function in the controller:

```
public function myEmailsShow($id)
{   
  $myEmails = DB::table('emails')->where('user_id',$id)->get();
  return view('content.myEmails', compact('myEmails'));
}
```

This is the a link where the user click to open the page:

```
@if(Auth::check())
  <a class="nav-link text-white" href="/myEmails/{id}"> my emails</a>
@endif
```

And here where i want to show the data (i am showing only the name for test):

```
<div class="row">
  @foreach($myEmails as $myEmail)
    {{$myEmail->name}}
  @endforeach
</div>
```

Comment: okay, so what is the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way to accomplish your goals here would be using a `hasMany` relationship between User and Emails (if emails is a Model).

```
//User.php

public function emails()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Email');
}
```

In the controller, apply the Auth middleware to the `myEmailsShow` method in a constructor:

```
//PagesController.php

public function __construct()
{
  $this->middleware('auth')->only(['myEmailsShow']);
}
```

Then, in your `myEmailsShow` method, do something like the following:

```
//PagesController.php

public function myEmailsShow()
{
    // Middleware Eliminates the need for ID in the function.
    $user = auth()->user();
    $myEmails = $user->emails;
    return view('content.myEmails', compact('myEmails'));
}
```

You can remove the ID parameter from the route and just make it something like `Route::get('/myEmails', 'PagesController@myEmailsShow');`. Only users who are logged in will be able to access this page, and they will only see emails belonging to them.

Comment: @salimbahouth Thanks! Can you mark the answer as correct? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`Route::get('/myEmails/{user}','PagesController@myEmailsShow')->name('myemails');`

with the controller

```
use App\Email; 
use App\User;


public function myEmailsShow(User $user)
{
///calling the model Email at parameters instead of $id eloquent automatically the data from DB 

    $myEmails = Email::where('user_id',$user->id)->get();
   
return view('content.myEmails')->with('myEmails', $myEmails);
}
```

The link has little modifications

```
@if(Auth::check())
       <a class="nav-link text-white" href="{{route('myemails', $user->id)}}"> my emails</a>
 @endif
```

displaying the value

```
@foreach($myEmails as $myEmail)
        {{$myEmail->name}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: One issue with this answer is that it would allow any logged in user to see all other users' emails. Although it certainly makes sense to choose to include the user ID in the URL, there should be a check in middleware to confirm that the user accessing the emails has permissions to do so.